# Warning: Error in [[.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, leaflet

I have a function which I'd like to handle multiple outputs but base it off of the input to the function. For example, in the following code side could refer to any number of maps on the page, e.g. 10:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("m1"),
  textOutput("m2")
)

f <- function(output, side) {
  m = output[[paste0('m', side)]]
  print(m)
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  f(output, 1)
  f(output, 2)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, running this code results in the following error:

```sh
Warning: Error in [[.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a reactive context for each output. This would be the first solution of doing it. This way you write a function that creates a `renderText` output in each call.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("in1", "Value"),
  textOutput("m1"),
  textOutput("m2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  f <- function(outputId, side) {
    output[[outputId]] <<- renderText({
      paste0('m', side, " - ", input$in1)
    })
  }
  
  f("m1", 1)
  f("m2", 2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The solution above duplicates code. For most apps that shouldn't be a problem. But if you need to avoid that:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("in1", "Value"),
  textOutput("m1"),
  textOutput("m2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  f <- function(outputId, side) {
      paste0('m', side, " - ", input$in1)
  }
  
  output$m1 <- renderText({
    f("m1", 1)
  })
  output$m2 <- renderText({
    f("m2", 2)
  })  

}
```